# KeyError on get request on Google Colab but not in local machine

Tags: python, python-requests, google-colaboratory

I'm very new to programming and I'm tring to run this code on Colab

```
import requests, datetime, hashlib, hmac, random, zlib, json


session_id = "my_id"
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.set("sessionid", session_id, domain=".tiktok.com")


url = "https://www.tiktok.com/passport/web/account/info/"
r = session.get(url)
print (r)

user_id = r.json()["data"]["user_id_str"]
print (user_id)
```

Colab returned with error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py:283: DeprecationWarning: `should_run_async` will not call `transform_cell` automatically in the future. Please pass the result to `transformed_cell` argument and any exception that happen during thetransform in `preprocessing_exc_tuple` in IPython 7.17 and above.
<Response [200]>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-6d746d6bbbb9> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 print (r)
     13 
---> 14 user_id = r.json()["data"]["user_id_str"]
     15 print (user_id)

KeyError: 'user_id_str'
```

While my local machine ran this code normally and returned this:

```
<Response [200]>
7048890068204110850
```

Comment: Try printing the JSON you get on your local machine, and on Colab.

Comment: The `url` does not have the `user_id_str` and there is no key as `["user_id_str"]` under `["data"]`.